# Check value in row mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have structure of table like this

```
id  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  ..... till  50 or 60
1   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I    J   K
2   G   H   A   B   C   D   L   M   N    O   P
3   So on ..
```

Now i want to find whether there is value G in first row . Help !

Comment: What you have tried tell us first???

Comment: Tried to search through row as we can in column.

Comment: where is your code or query which u tried??

Comment: What is your table trying to represent?

Comment: see i am just creating conditions in my mind and tying to solve , this condition can be useful if users are less but their options and info is more

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). I believe something like this is what you're after?

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE CONCAT(1,2,3,4,5,6......50) LIKE '%G%';

SELECT id, LOCATE('G', CONCAT(1,2,3,4,5,6......50)) FROM table WHERE CONCAT(1,2,3,4,5,6......50) LIKE '%G%';
```

Comment: Can you explain why they're increasing ? Perhaps we can help you find a better structure for your database

Comment: the same we use with rows i just tried to use with columns , inserting new columns  and keep one's info in columns , actually i did it because    usersare less but rows are increasing and there can be more rows than column

Comment: how to find coulmn id with this method which is having  'G ' like value

Comment: i have to write 2 one ?  and how to collect it

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your structure should look like this:

```
ValueMatrix Struc
----------------------
row_id      INT
column_id   INT
value       VARCHAR(1)
```

And entered data like this:

```
ValueMatrix Data
----------------------
row_id      column_id   value
1           1           A
1           2           B
1           3           C
2           1           G
2           2           H
2           3           A
```

And so query to retrieve value G:

```
SELECT *
FROM ValueMatrix
WHERE row_id = 1 AND value='G'
```